# Jenkins Build failed

Tags: selenium, jenkins

Building remotely on Local in workspace D:/CI/RepoWS/ZipcrimCS
New run name is '#60 Auto-test SmartClient (Dev) by user Kuldeep Rawat'
Path To VSTest.console.exe: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"
Executing VSTest: cmd.exe /C C:\Users\TECHAD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\vstest7683597382007476941.bat && exit %ERRORLEVEL%
[ZipcrimCS] $ cmd.exe /C C:\Users\TECHAD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\vstest7683597382007476941.bat && exit %ERRORLEVEL%

D:\CI\RepoWS\ZipcrimCS>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "DEV/AutomatedTest/bin/Dev/AutomationCisive.dll" /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory="SMC"" /Enablecodecoverage /Platform:x64 /Framework:Framework45 /Logger:trx 
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.9.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.5 and platform X64. Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings.
AutomationCisive.dll is built for Framework 4.7.2 and Platform AnyCPU.
Go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=236877&clcid=0x409 for more details on managing these settings.

2.091
Data collector 'Code Coverage' message: Cannot find CodeCoverage.exe..
NUnit Adapter 3.16.1.0: Test execution started
Running all tests in D:\CI\RepoWS\ZipcrimCS\DEV/AutomatedTest/bin/Dev/AutomationCisive.dll
   NUnit3TestExecutor converted 13 of 13 NUnit test cases
Starting ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.69 (6813546031a4bc83f717a2ef7cd4ac6ec1199132-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#776}) on port 43363
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Failed   TheUserLogsInAndSeesTheSmartClientBasicInfoPage
Error Message:
 OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 120 seconds
  ----> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#NewCaseFormButton"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.122)
S

Comment: `Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#NewCaseFormButton"}` are you sure this element is present ?

Comment: yes this element is present when i Run the tests pass locally in visual studio but fail in Jenkins